# Incompatible types .Required java.lang.Integer found java.lang.String

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

```
class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, Integer>, Void, Integer> {
    private static MyApi myApiService = null;
    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Pair<Context, Integer>... params) {
        if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }});
            myApiService = builder.build();}
        context = params[0].first;
        int name = params[0].second;
        try {
            return myApiService.addition(name).execute().getNo1();
           // return myApiService.addition(name).execute().getNo1();
        } catch (IOException e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I want to send a no to google app engine from android endpoint.and want a number to be displayed on the google app engine page .But in return e.getMessage(); I found error incompatible types

Comment: where is `e.getMessage();` ?

Comment: I wrote e.getMessage but was getting error so converted it to getInteger but still getting error

Comment: `IOException` or anything it derives from does not have `getInteger()` method. We have no clue what does the `getNo1()` method return. In your question you say `e.getMessage()`, but we don't see that in your code.

Comment: this is an AsyncTask i assume? put more of the code you have written. and put the code from where it is called.

Comment: `e.getMessage()` returns a `string`, not `int` ...

Comment: e.getMessage() is the error StackTrace message... Which will never be an integer... You shouldn't use the stacktrace as a value... But handle the error in another way

Comment: why not just log the error. why would you return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
>     Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
> ```

(If "result" is not a resource ID)

Toast.makeText() takes String as 2nd parameter.

Try

```
Toast.makeText(context, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(MyBean myBean) {

        Toast.makeText(myBean.getNo1(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Comment: for the above code I am getting this error  "cannot resolve method maketext java.lang.Integer,int".which I  posted now

Comment: Toast.makeText() takes 3 parameters.(You have only 2.)  So, error shows "method not found"